# How can i fill a table with values from a dropdownlist in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to fill an html table with the selecteditem from a dropdownlist, I already passed the database data to this list, and I also get all the information of the selected value through an actionresult, so the thing I want is when I select an item, put it in the table, and do this every time I want so I can add various values at the same time. does anyone have any idea how to do it?

This is my model

```
public partial class Producto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Precio { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List <Producto> Listasnom { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable < SelectListItem > ProductoListItems  
        {  
            get  
            {  
                return new SelectList(Listasnom ?? new List<Producto>(), "Id", "Nombre"); 
            }  
        } 
}
```

My controller

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

       [HttpGet] 
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Pedido.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {    
            var lista = new Producto();    
            lista.Listasnom = db.Producto.ToList();

            return View(lista);
        }  

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Producto producto)
        {    
            var lista = new Producto();     
            lista.Listasnom = db.Producto.ToList();

            var emp = lista.Listasnom.Where(e => e.Id == producto.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            lista.Id = emp.Id;
            lista.Nombre = emp.Nombre; 
            lista.Precio = emp.Precio;

            return View(lista);                
        }
```

and my view:

```
@model punto.Models.Producto

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
        <div class="box-body">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Producto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.ProductoListItems, "Elegir Producto", new { @class = "form-control"}) 
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Agregar</button> 
        </div>
</form>
```

This is the table where I want to put the values

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
            <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>Id</th>                 
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nombre)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Precio) </td>
                    </tr> 
</table>
```

I don't have any idea how to do it, if someone can help me.

Comment: use onchange on dropdownlist, send selected Id through ajax to  controller, in controller return data to ajax, and in ajax success use jquery to put data to table.

Comment: I can do this in the same actionresult create? Sorry im new in this

Comment: Is your `Create` method just to display the current selected product data in a table? you could try to use partial view to display the data .Show more details on what you want

Comment: @XueliChen yes for now i just get the current select product, but i want to store this value in the table so i can select more products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select more products and store them in the table , you could try to use ajax as Nhien said :

View :

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Producto
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Producto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.ProductoListItems, "Elegir Producto", new { @class = "form-control",id="selectlist" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="btnCreate" class="btn btn-info">Agregar</button>
    </div>
</div>

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#selectlist").change(function () {
        var id = $("#selectlist").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/products/getproduct?id=" + id,
            success: function (data) {
                var tBody = $("#example1 > TBODY")[0];
                var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

                //Add ID cell.
                var cell = $(row.insertCell(0));
                cell.html(data.id);
                //Add Nombre cell.
                cell = $(row.insertCell(1));
                cell.html(data.nombre);
                //Add Precio cell.
                cell = $(row.insertCell(2));
                cell.html(data.precio);

            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Controller :

```
 public IActionResult GetProduct(int id)
 {
        var selectProduct = db.Producto.Find(id);
        return Json(selectProduct);
 }
```

Comment: ok i try it this but when i click on submit button "Agregar" don't add anything to the table

Comment: i changed the url to "url: "/Producto/GetProduct?Id=" + id," and the cells to their respective variables

Comment: when you change dropdown, talbe will auto add data which get from ajax.

Comment: @Nhien still the function dont add the cell to the table, maybe im doing something wrong but i dont know what

Comment: ok i got it to work, thank you both for help, last question, how can i call this function in my submit button instead of add it everytime i change the dropdown?

Comment: change  $("#selectlist").change(function()) to function yourname()
and   <button onclick="yourname()" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Agregar</button>

Comment: It doesnt do nothing that way, i need to pass him some value? @Nhien

Comment: no just remove type = submit in button, add onclick to button  <button onclick="yourname()" class="btn btn-info">Agregar</button> and $("#selectlist").change(function () {} to function yourname(),